# Is there a regularized width of yellow taxiway ground bands?

Tags: regulations, taxiing, airport-markings

What is the width of the yellow stripes that are painted on the ground of the taxiway?

Is it the same on the whole taxiway or does it vary from an area to another? Is it mentioned in the aerodrome design manual issued by the international organization of civil aviation?

Comment: Hello there, welcome to Aviation.SE. Nice and interesting question!

Comment: See 5.2.8.10 in ICAO Chicago Convention [annex 14](http://cockpitdata.com/Software/ICAO%20Annex%2014%20Volume%201) ("*A taxiway centre line marking shall be at least 15 cm in width*")

Comment: @kevin thanks mate :)

Comment: @mins thank you, that's what I was looking for! is there a max value to the line marking width though?

Comment: No maximum at the ICAO recommendations level, however any country may deviate from or complement ICAO, differences should be explained in AIP (GEN-1.7). To relate to Noah's answer for FAA, in [USA AIP](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/AIP.pdf), this would be in GEN 1.7−86, but there is nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [FAA's document about standards for airport markings](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150_5340_1l.pdf), it says:

> **e.** Characteristics.
>
> (1)
>
> Width. The taxiway centerline marking width, which is either 6 inches (15
>   cm) or 12 inches (30 cm), is based on the type of taxiing operation as described below. Uniform
>   width must be maintained for the entire length of the taxiway except under the following
>   conditions.
>
> (i)
>
> The taxiway or part of the taxiway is designated as a SMGCS taxi
>   route. Under this designation, the width of the taxiway centerline must be 12 inches (30 cm)
>   wide and, on light-colored pavement, further outlined in black. The taxiway centerline width of
>   any remaining section of the taxiway that is not part of the designated SMGCS taxi route may
>   change abruptly at that point or at the intersection with other taxiway centerline markings, for
>   example, reduced from 12 inches (30 cm) to 6 inches (15 cm).

[Source](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150_5340_1l.pdf), chapter *Taxiway Center Lines*, page 43

For the taxiway edge lines, following rules apply:

> **e.** Characteristics.
>
> (1)
>   The outermost edge of both marking schemes must be painted along the
>   edge of the usable pavement.
>
> (2)
>   The continuous taxiway edge marking consists of dual, continuous lines
>   with each line being at least 6 inches (15 cm) in width and spaced 6 inches (15 cm) apart (edge to edge) [...]

[Source](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/150_5340_1l.pdf), chapter *Taxiway Edge Lines*, page 48

---

This really is a great question, I have never thought about airport markings being such a complex thing.

[image: complex runway markings...]

Comment: thanks @Noah Krasser, I guess the regulations of the international organization of civil aviation are applied in all airports of the world, is it the case for the federal aviation administration (since it is an american administration and not an international one)?

Comment: @user2651062  ICAO isn't a regulatory body per se, and it doesn't issue regulations. There are ICAO standards and recommendations, but each sovereign nation implements those as it sees fit, publishing (somewhere) whatever they do differently so that pilots can know what to expect.  Generally the FAA doesn't deviate too much from the ICAO stuff, although as the answers & comments above show, they may be somewhat different (i.e. ICAO is 15 cm or more, FAA is 15 cm (exactly) in *this* case, and 30 cm (exactly) in *that* case. Another nation might make all stripes 20 cm wide, etc).

Comment: Just because you have a standard, doesn't necessarily mean it is implemented consistently. ;-)